# Is there a production ready UI for managing CoreOS

Tags: coreos

I've played around with [Panamax](http://panamax.io) as a solution for managing groups of containers on a single server CoreOS installation, but it lacks several features, notably fleet management and user based access restriction.
Finally, the project does not seem to be maintained anymore.

Are there any active and production ready alternatives that make the management of multiple CoreOS servers possible via a UI (Web or desktop)?

Comment: another issue: Panamax project seems to be abandoned :/

Answer (score 2):

Have not yet tried this yet, but [Mist.io](http://mist.io) seems like a very promising option.  Comes in both an [open source](https://github.com/mistio/mist.io) and SaaS version. Open Source version is being actively maintained and their service is production ready for an impressive list of cloud providers. The UI gives options for managing and monitoring CoreOS clusters at both the OS and container levels: you can spin up new hosts and new containers from the same UI. Might be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

The container manager for fleet is fleet-browser:
https://github.com/cloudwalkio/fleet-browser

Here is the unit file I use to deploy it, just change the lines where I have put "YOURBLAH", etc.

```
[Unit]
Description=Expose Fleet API in a nice GUI
Requires=docker.service
After=docker.service  

[Service]
EnvironmentFile=/etc/environment
KillMode=none
TimeoutStartSec=0
Restart=always
RestartSec=10s
ExecStartPre=-/usr/bin/docker kill fleet-browser
ExecStartPre=-/usr/bin/docker rm fleet-browser
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/docker pull cloudwalk/fleet-browser:latest
ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker run --net=host --rm --name fleet-browser \
 -e FLEET_ENDPOINT=YOURENDPOINT:8081 \
 -e ETCD_ENDPOINT=YOURENDPOINT:2379 \
 -p 5000:5000 cloudwalk/fleet-browser:latest
ExecStop=/usr/bin/docker stop fleet-browser

[X-Fleet]
MachineMetadata="server-type=YOURSERVERTYPE" "node=YOURNODENAME"
```